# @Post in Rest Service accepting Json Values

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have been trying to learn @POST to create webservices using Jersey. 
I can now fully adapt the @Get and @Post using the normal params.
For example,

```
@POST
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response postMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "POST:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

However, I am not sure how I am suppose to accept JSON message and either create or process it through the url.

Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Data Transfer Object which will be used to consume JSON send from UI and use it directly. @Consume can be used to configure data type format send from UI It can be JSON or Form submit etc

```
@POST
@Path("/{param}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response postMsg(UserData userData) {
   ...
}


public class UserData {

    private String userName;
    private String userAddress;
    ... 
    define getter setter 

}


// UI JSON call 

    var url = "rest/employee";
    var type = "POST";
    var data = {
        userName : $("#txtEmpFirstName").val(),
        userAddress : $("#txtEmpLastName").val(),
    };


    $.ajax({
        type : type,
        url : url,
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success : function(data) {
             alert(data.Success);
             resetEmployee();
             searchEmployee();
        }, error : function(error){ alert(JSON.stringify(error.responseText));}
    });
```

Comment: this is a good one, but i don't want to put a {param} in the link. I would like to be able to test from rest client testers like postman.

Comment: You can define your onw url someting like this @Path("/users") only condition is it has to be unique across application.

Answer (score 0):

`@Consumes` annotation is used to specify which MIME media types of representations a resource can accept.
Follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggqqr/) for better understanding.

Comment: how about returning JSON